# Attachment in a Custom List Form at different position

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, attachments

I am trying to create a custom form having 5 buttons on it at different sections. on click of button i have to attach "n" number of document, and show at the same section. In the same way have to do for reset of the section.

Anyone has done such thing earlier. If so, pl. suggest the solution.